# Android disable usb connection via adb shell

Tags: android, usb, adb

I need to disable and enable the connection to the USB device programmatically. I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
echo "suspend" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/level"
```

I can only set the values "on"and " auto". I also tried this.

```
echo "1-2" > "/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind"
```

This works, but destroys the current activity (not my app). Is there a way to disable and enable the connection without destroying the activity? I have root access.